# Select whole item in ListBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, listboxitem

I've been googling around for something similar to FullRowSelect for a listview. Currently my listbox items are only selectable if you click on a part of it that is being taken up with content eg a textblock, item etc. This means that the "clickable" area is dependant on how long the entry is, but ideally i'd like to be able to click anywhere within the rectangle that defines each item.

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `ItemContainerStyle` within the `ListBox` so that its `HorizontalContentAlignment` is set as `Stretch` versus `Left`. You can still align the content within the `ListBoxItem` as needed.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Stretched" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Stretched}">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="100"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="100"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```